# Failed to load a service: io.micronaut.context.exceptions.BeanContextException: | Micronaut

Tags: java, micronaut

I have just created a file named `TransactionsRepository.java`. I am not calling this class anywhere as of now

**TransactionsRepository.java**

```java
package com.example.Transactions;

import io.micronaut.data.annotation.Repository;

// @Repository
public interface TransactionsRepository {
}
```

Whenever I run ./gradlew run, it runs perfectly, but the moment I uncomment this line, it throws an error

```
@Repository
```

**ERROR**

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to load a service: io.micronaut.context.exceptions.BeanContextException: Unexpected error loading be
> an definition [com.example.$Transactions.TransactionsRepository$Intercepted$Definition]: failed to access class com.example.Transactions.TransactionsRepository$In
> tercepted from class com.example.$Transactions.TransactionsRepository$Intercepted$Definition$Reference (com.example.Transactions.TransactionsRepository$Intercepte
> d and com.example.$Transactions.TransactionsRepository$Intercepted$Definition$Reference are in unnamed module of loader 'app')

I even tried doing this but still does not work

```java
@Repository
public interface TransactionsRepository extends  CrudRepository<Transaction, Long>{
}
```

I have also included below line in my gradle file

`annotationProcessor("io.micronaut.data:micronaut-data-hibernate-jpa")`

---

I am very new to micronaut. Its been hours I am trying this. I dont know whats wrong in this code. Please help me if I am missing something.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's probably the package name - package sub-names should not start with uppercase letters. Change `com.example.Transactions` to `com.example.transactions` (and rename the directory from `Transactions` to `transactions`.

Comment: Wish I could upvote u twice. You saved my life. By the way is to ok to name something like `emailParser`?

Comment: Typically type (class/interface/enum/etc.) names start with a capital letter and variables start with a lowercase letter. So you'd name the class `EmailParser` but when working with an instance of it, name the variable `emailParser`. See https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/codeconventions-namingconventions.html

Comment: Took far to long to pinpoint this as the issue. Thank you!